# The TCP server send() function blocks when the network cable is unplugged

Tags: c++11

I encountered a problem: I implemented a TCP socket server. When listening to a client connection, I set a timer (another thread) to send data to the client, but the client does not send data to the server, and all APIs are blocked.

When I use a TCP socket client tool to connect to the server, I can normally listen to data from the server. By manually closing the client and reconnecting, I can also listen to data from the server. However, this tool connects to the server and successfully connects and receives data.

At this point, I disconnect the network cable and then connect it back. Once the connection is successful, I can no longer receive data, I have checked that my timer thread is working properly. The problem is that the send function in the timer thread is blocked.

May I know how to handle this issue? I have set the TCP heartbeat.

Comment: If a connection is broken, you have to reestablish it. Is it done on both the client and server side?

Comment: @Some programmer dude     The TCP server determines whether the connection is disconnected by returning the send function, but at this point, the send function is blocked, so the TCP server cannot determine whether the connection is disconnected.this is my question.

Comment: Perhaps use non-blocking sockets, and possibly `select`/`poll` to check if you can write or receive from a connection?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is there any other way besides setting it as a non blocking function?

Comment: Can a blocking function like this fail to return even when the network cable is disconnected? Can only wait for the client to actively send a disconnection signal?

Comment: Unless you have a keep-alive signaling scheme set up (either your own, or using the TCP `SO_KEEPALIVE` option (which defaults to a *very* long time) there's really no way to find out on a receiving end that the network have been disconnected somewhere. When sending, TCP will do a lot of retries with increasing timeouts, so it can take a long time for it to figure out if there's something wrong. Some of the retries and timeouts can be changed with `setsockopt`, but it will be a relatively long timeout anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254677/discussion-between-yanzhang-guo-and-some-programmer-dude).

Answer (score 1):

My problem has been solved. I didn't use select/poll/epoll, I just added the MSG_DONTWAIT option in the send function.
Originally, if TCP was not set to non blocking when the network was disconnected, it would be in a blocking state.

```
send(this->rwfd[i], buf, size, MSG_NOSIGNAL|MSG_DONTWAIT)
```